# Merge branch in release manager

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release management release pipeline which is setup like this:

```
Artifacts >> Development (trigger on build success) >> Production (manual trigger after Development)
```

What I'd like to do, is merge Development branch into Master on promotion from Development to Master, so master always has production version code, but release agent doesnt pull git repo and has no access to git. I've found [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/11701839-gitflow-in-release-management) which indicates that this is not possible (at least without hacks). Any pointers appreciated.

I'm using github.com, not vsts repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge development branch into master branch in a VSTS release environment, you can achieve it by adding a **PowerShell task**. Details as below:

Add a PowerShell task with the script:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repo repo
cd repo
git checkout development
git checkout master
git merge development 
git push origin master
```

**Note:**

- The Fail on Standard Error option should be deselected in PowerShell task.

  [image]
- The PowerShell task will fail if there has merge conflicts during merging `development` branch into `master` branch. So you'd better add `-X` option for `git merge` command:

  ```
  git merge development -X theirs  #Resolve the merge conflict files by keeping the version on development branch
  git merge development -X ours    #Resolve the merge conflict files by keeping the version on master branch
  ```

Comment: yeah, this is kinda obvious, but this is a hack, i'm talking about a proper way of doing this

Comment: Do you mean merge development branch into master branch automatically by VSTS release management? As you found in the user voice, the merge action need to be customerized by users (not by VSTS itself).

Comment: i ended up doing pretty much this